# CORS issue in fetch from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, callout

I am trying to get data from another system in my LWC with the help of the fetch method and not able to get it as i am getting below error:

```
"Access to fetch  from origin 'https://--dev....' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."
```

I have added the URL in the remote site setting and CSP setting in the salesforce as well.

kindly help me out for this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situation before. After they onboarded my application, I was able to make a callout using Fetch API.

You have to ask 3rd party application to onboard your application. When I said onboarding I meant they have to whitelist your salesforce ORG URL and bypass IP restrictions if any.

Comment: but some of the URL it is working fine.

Comment: Does the some URL similar to the URL that you are hitting? URL where you're getting an error must be different from some URL that you mentioned? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes..just i am appending one id at the end..

Comment: that is only diffrence here

Comment: are you making callout via Apex with same URL? If yes then making callout to apex would not face CORS Issue. If you try to make a callout using Apex instead of apex then you would not see an issue.

Comment: Nope..that also in LWC...

Comment: If you can share sample code of Fetch API which is working and sample of Fetch API which is not working then it would help us to provide you possible solution.